# jackson - jackson not creating json for nested objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I have a user list class and an API that returns user list and total records.
The class is as follows :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class FMSResponseInfo {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Object data;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserListResDTO {

    @JsonProperty("users")
    private List<UserDTO> users;
    @JsonProperty("totalRecords")
    private long totalRecords;

    public List<UserDTO> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(List<UserDTO> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public long getTotalRecords() {
        return totalRecords;
    }
    public void setTotalRecords(long totalRecords) {
        this.totalRecords = totalRecords;
    }
}
```

I am setting an object of type UserListResDTO in FMSResponseInfo as shown below.

I have been successful in creating web services and returning response as json, so far. But the problem I am facing is that the API returns the response as follows : 
**{"data":"org.package.UserListResDTO@70783307","message":"Success","status":"200"}**

And this is how I have written the web service :

```
    @Path("/getUsers")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public FMSResponseInfo getUsers(@QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("0") int page) {
        System.out.println("In getUsers()");
        FMSResponseInfo fmsResponseInfo = new FMSResponseInfo();
        try {
            UserListResDTO userList = fmsUserManager.getAllUsers(page);
            fmsResponseInfo.setData(userList);
            fmsResponseInfo.setStatus(FMSErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS_CODE.getValue());
            fmsResponseInfo.setMessage(FMSErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS_MESSAGE.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return FMSUtil.getErrorResponseInfo(FMSErrorMessageEnum.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_CODE.getValue(),
                    e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Out getUsers()");
        return fmsResponseInfo;
    }
```

I guess there is some problem with the dependencies or something that I am unable to resolve. Major dependencies in my pom are :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and I am creating Web services by extending Application class as follow :

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class FMSApplication extends Application {    
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses(){
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(FMSUserManagerWebService.class);
        set.add(FMSDocumentManagerWebService.class);
        set.add(FMSInboxManagerWebService.class);
        set.add(FMSLocationManagerWebService.class);
        return set;
    }       
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated as I am new to this REST web services and have been stuck for quite long.

Comment: I have added the code of Web service now, can you please check and suggest what is the problem ?

Comment: Please include the code for FMSResponseInfo.

Comment: Could you change the moxy to jackson and try? <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @BPS ok I am adding !!

Comment: @ShireResident ok trying

Comment: Hey @ShireResident this worked !! :D Thanks a lott, I am a getting a proper response , can you please give a reason or explain the difference between the two ? That would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link will explain the answer

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7963

> 9.1.1.1. POJO support
>
> POJO support represents the easiest way to convert your Java Objects
>   to JSON and back.
>
> Media modules that support this approach are MOXy and Jackson

The link to Jackson includes

> 9.1.4.1. Dependency
>
> To use Jackson 2.x as your JSON provider you need to add
>   jersey-media-json-jackson module to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>  
</dependency>
```

I don't know much about moxy but you had jackson on your CLASSPATH and were using Jackson annonations. Jersey however was configured to use moxy.

From link

> JSON binding support via MOXy is a default and preferred way of
>   supporting JSON binding in your Jersey applications since Jersey 2.0.
>   **When JSON MOXy module is on the class-path, Jersey will automatically
>   discover the module and seamlessly enable JSON binding support via
>   MOXy in your applications**.

MOXy seemed to have handled FMSResponseInfo. Why it didn't handle the other object I do not know. But since you wanted to use Jackson you should have been using the Jackson module.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Shire Resident in the comments using the following dependency I was able to resolve the problem :

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId> 
  <version>2.22.2</version> 
</dependency>
```